# Using shodan from the terminal

Tags: python

I've been looking forward to downloading the command-line interface for "Shodan".

On the website they say that i basically have to type "pip install -U --user shodan" in my cmd, so i did multiple times and it now says that the requirement are already satisfied, which feels normal since i did it multiple times trying to fix said problem.

Now the problem is, next step is to basically type "shodan" in the cmd, problem is it says 'shodan' isn't recognized.

What am i supposed to do ! :(

Comment: first of all the question title is not convenient. secondly, please set your environment variables. you should define the environment variable correctly to be able to run your command through cmd.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path of the scripts to your system PATH variable:

It is something like this:

```
C:\Python38\Scripts
```

When you run pip install, it installs an exe file under the Scripts folder of your python installation. You should add this path to the PATH variable as described in the link. This makes the exe available in the terminal.

See this guide for more information:
https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: By adding the path, do you mean i have to manually create folder Scripts in another folder that is in Python38 which is contained in C ?, because the folder already exists and shodan is NOT in that folder

Comment: When you run pip install, it installs an exe file under the Scripts folder of your python installation. You should add this path to the PATH variable as described in the link. This makes the exe available in the terminal.

Comment: @Thatonenewguy Consider marking my answer if it has solved your problem.